# How to create a windows registry watcher?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, registry

How to create a windows registry watcher application using .Net,

I want this application to watch all the registry hooks and fire an event when a value change, this event will tell the **old and new value** for that value.

Thats possible? how? need just the idea or where to start

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at [RegistryMonitor - a .NET wrapper class for RegNotifyChangeKeyValue](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4502/RegistryMonitor-a-NET-wrapper-class-for-RegNotifyC).

Comment: Not a big fan of that approach because it just synchronously sits on a thread, waiting for changes.

Answer (score 2):

.Net framework does not contain embedded class to watch the registry.
But you still can use wrapped WinAPI calls or WMI interface (see [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WMI_RegistryMonitor.aspx))

Answer (score 2):

The subscription can be done either [via WMI](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2494270) or directly via blocking [RegNotifyChangeKeyValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms724892.aspx) call in a separate thread, and you'll [have to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19888347/how-to-tell-which-value-triggered-regnotifychangekeyvalue) monitor the old and the new values for yourself. [Here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.regnotifychangekeyvalue) is the code.