# Monitor changes to the registry

Tags: c#, .net, registry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a windows registry watcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846366/how-to-create-a-windows-registry-watcher)

Are there any classes in .net I can use to monitor any change to a value in the registry, similar to how FileSystemWatcher works.

So if the value is changed, an event is raised.

Or any other suggestions to do this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a built in function for this, but you can easily create your own by using a timer, checking the value of a key, remembering that value, and comparing it again during the next tick and see if the value is different.