# How to tell which value triggered RegNotifyChangeKeyValue?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

I am using [RegNotifyChangeKeyValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724892.aspx) API to track changes to my registry key and the C++ example similar to the one given at the bottom of that MSDN page. I set this API as such:

```
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"Software\\Company\\Product", 0, KEY_NOTIFY, &hKey);
RegNotifyChangeKeyValue(hKey, FALSE, REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_SET, hEvent, TRUE);
```

So, say, when the event that this API takes as a parameters is signaled (which means a change to the `Software\Company\Product` key) is there any way to find out which value actually triggered it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You need to cache the current name/value pairs AFTER the call to RegNotifyChangeKeyValue, and then when signaled you can compare the latest name/value pairs to your cache to see what is different, and then update your cache for the next signal.

If you build your cache BEFORE the RegNotifyChangeKeyValue call, and an update is made by some thread between the two operations, your cache will NOT reflect the actual state, and that MAY cause problems on the next update (depending on your needs).

Building the cache AFTER the RegNotifyChangeKeyValue MAY cause your code being signaled but being unable to know what value is concerned (if the update is made by another thread between the two operations). No big deal: just pretend to not seing any change.

Comment: Thanks. I thought so too. What I'm trying to avoid though is reading ALL the values from that key. It sounded like such a waste of CPU cycles when only one or two values were changed. But a possible race condition that you brought up does explain things.