# How to use RegNotifyChangeKeyValue

Tags: c#, vb.net, registry, pinvoke

How can I use the RegNotifyChangeKeyValue API to notify me if the RegistryValue "MyValue" in the key

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Test

has been changed.
For example if a value with the name "MyValue" has created in this path:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Test

Show a messageBox "Created"

if it has been delete, show a msgbox deleted and if it has been changed, show a msgbox "changed".
I am not sure how to use this API so can someone maybe help me out?

Comment: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.regnotifychangekeyvalue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/846366