# How can I send one bit of information from a WPF app to a Windows service?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, windows, visual-studio, windows-services

I have two projects within the same solution. One is a Windows service and one is a WPF app. If a certain event happens, I need to send one bit of information to the service to notify it to do something. My first idea was making the application settings of the service public and adding the service as a reference in the WPF app. This didn't seem to work. Ideally I need a single place where I can store a persistent bit that can be changed by either the service or the app, regardless of whether the other one is running. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Stick it in a reg key and have them poll it.

Comment: I would also use a registry key or if u dont want to use that, i would place a file in appdata and change a value in it and let the service run a filesystemwatcher on it and then let your code run on the filesystemwatcher changed event

Comment: Actually you don't even have to poll it; you can create a watcher of course: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846366/how-to-create-a-windows-registry-watcher